# How to define the image source from the content of an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, image, url

I have an html link 'localurl' pointing to an URL of an image (for example the current album artwork of the music playing on my sonos), so that when I give 'localurl' in my browser, it doesn't display the image directly but a path like 'http://image.png'. This last path links to the image.

I would like to display this image in an HTML file using the 'localurl'. I think it should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body > 

    <img src=getUrlFromHTML('localurl') >

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getUrlFromHTML(url)
        {
            ...
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: the link 'http://image.png' is not always the same, I don't know it in advance, this is why in need to go with 'localurl'. The concept is the following: I have an openHAB installation with the Sonos Binding, I have a string item called Sonos_CurrentAlbumArtUrl and through the API of openHAB, i get the link http://openhab.local:8080/rest/items/Sonos_CurrentAlbumArtUrl/state (this is my 'localurl' and it is pointing to 'http://image.png' which depends on the music being played on the Sonos (using Spotify). I hope this is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the time to learn some javascript and I found an answer that fits to my need. I share here the content of the HTML-body as I think it could help others.

```
    <body>
        <img id="SonosAlbumArt">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var link = 'http://openhab.local:8080/rest/items/Sonos_CurrentAlbumArtUrl/state';
            var img = document.getElementById('SonosAlbumArt');
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () { refreshAlbumArt()} );

            function sendAlbumArtRequest() {
                xhr.open('GET', link);
                xhr.send(null);
            }

            function refreshAlbumArt() {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    img.src = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }

            setInterval(sendAlbumArtRequest, 1000);

         </script>
    </body>
```

I am not quite convinced that the `setInterval` is the best way to do it. I miss something like an event triggered when the album art changes, in order to not send requests each second. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to refer selected files from  `<input type=file` you dont need to use javascript. 
you can just write the location. For locations you can drag image to your browser, copy from the address bar.

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/nerkn/Documents/cobokin.jpg"
```